# List cells without spaces, based on another qualifying cell

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010

I have two columns, one has text values and another with has corresponding Yes/No text values.

In another column I'd like to list the values of the first column **if** the answer in the adjacent column is "no". How would I go about doing this **without spaces being in the "Yes" items**? I can't figure out the IF/then logic.

**This is for a form so I need it to do this automatically.**

Example:

```
| Item |   | Is Fruit? |                       | List of Fruit |

 Apples        Yes                                  Apples
 Oranges       Yes                                  Oranges
 Broccoli      No                                   Peaches
 Carrots       No
 Peaches       Yes
```

**I do not want**:

```
| Item |   | Is Fruit? |                       | List of Fruit |

 Apples        Yes                                  Apples
 Oranges       Yes                                  Oranges
 Broccoli      No                                   [BLANK]
 Carrots       No                                   [BLANK]
 Peaches       Yes                                  Peaches
```

Comment: Try http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx, or http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/612681-array-formula-how-to-aggegrate-data-removing-blank-cells.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With layout as shown:

[image]

this formula works:

```
{=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IFERROR(1/SIGN((C:C=A$1))*ROW($1:$5),6),ROWS(B$1:B1)),1),"")=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IFERROR(1/SIGN((C:C=A$1))*ROW($1:$5),6),ROWS(B$1:B1)),1),""))}
```

(where `6` is the total rows to apply to) but it is slow and not what I would recommend. My preference would be to accept the blanks in the first instance, copy that column to a spare sheet, filter to remove blanks and copy back.

I have added `Yes` in `A1` in case you really wish to change this to `no`.